# Как изучать последовательно Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать Javascript, но сразу же был озадачен обилием все возможных react, redux, es6, typescript... jQuery уже не в моде, а я как раз щас прошел базовый курс по js и jQuery. И в свете всех новых технологий не совсем понятно, как по шагам должно идти обучение Javascript. Буду благодарен, если поможете в этом вопросе!

Я сам по себе занимаюсь версткой и обычно все скрипты просто подключаю, но стало интересно научиться писать самому приложения на Javascript по всем современным технологиям.

Comment: Для каждого все индивидуально, и нет абсолютно точной стратегии обучения. Учите то что вам интересно и кажется необходимым. Этот вопрос больше подходит для обсуждений на форумах

Comment: Здравствуйте! Начните с learn.javascript.ru, очень хороший учебник, после, я думаю, вы уже сами поймёте что вам нужно.

Comment: Напишу своё мнение: `es6`, `vue.js` это прогрессивные и классные штуки. `Jquery`, устарел. Мой опыт показывает что связка `react + typescript + redux` достаточно неудобная, много проблем, поэтому я перешёл на `vue.js`, то что на том стеке делается мега запутанно и нужно обладать кучей знаний на `vue.js` делается быстро и красиво + отличная русская документация и сообщество, экосистема. Это моё мнение, привожу без доказательств. Рекомендую если есть желание понять что к чему поверхностно просмотреть разные технологии, не изучая их глубины, и понять что больше нравится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Начните с learn.javascript.ru, очень хороший учебник, после, я думаю, вы уже сами поймёте что вам нужно.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку!